# HTML in data of theme_table()

Tags: theming, 8

I created a table in my custom page using the following code.

```php
$build = [
  'table' => [
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#rows' => $rows,
  ],
];
```

The first row is the following one.

```php
$row = [
  'billing' => [
  'data' => $invoice . '<small>' . $label . '</small>',
];
```

In the page, the `<small>` tag is displayed as plain text. I tried to add `attributes => ['html']`, but it doesn't work.

How can I render HTML markup in a table row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FormattableMarkup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Render!FormattableMarkup.php/class/FormattableMarkup/8.2.x) to insert variables into html markup:

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

  'data' => new FormattableMarkup('<b>@bar</b>', ['@bar' => $foo]);
```

Comment: Nice. It's working. But why I need to do that ?

Comment: For security reasons twig escapes by default all variables, for example `<` gets `&lt;`. That's why you see the html tags displayed as clear text, if you not use a markup object, which is considered by Twig as safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  // Build row
  $rows[ $one_nid ] = array(
    'title' => array(
      'data' => $one_node->getTitle(),
      'class' => 'donkey',
    ),
    'price_change_today' => array(
      'data' => array(
        '#markup' => $price_change.'<span class="price-change-icon"></span>'.$price_percent_change,
      ),
      'class' => 'burro',
    ),
  );

// Return render array for table
return array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $headers,
  '#rows' => $rows,
);
?>
```